# How can I resolve "Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query." error?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have 2 date fields of dateTime data type each.

One is called PhaseEnd and the other is PhaseStart.

We would like to substract PhaseStart from PhaseEnd to get the number of months between the two.

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN PhaseEnd IS NOT NULL THEN round((PhaseEnd - PhaseStart)/30,1)
       ELSE round((getdate() - PhaseStart)/30,1) END) Months from tblT_PHASES
```

I get `Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.`

Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Use `DATEADD` or `DATEDIFF` instead of `-`?

Answer (score 1):

use [datediff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

```
select
    case
        when PhaseEnd is not null then
            round(datediff(day, PhaseStart, PhaseEnd)/30,1)
        else
            round(datediff(day, PhaseStart, getdate())/30,1)
    end as Months
from tblT_PHASES
```

or

```
select
   round(
       datediff(day, PhaseStart, isnull(PhaseEnd, getdate())) / 30
   , 1) as Months
from tblT_PHASES
```

Comment: If you use `month` then the /30 calculation no longer applies - did you mean `day`?

Comment: yep, thanks. Well there could be a different opinions what is difference in months..

Comment: thanks very much. The first part of your solution, @RomanPekar Works.

The second part is way off with strange numbers.

Comment: beware that it gives you number of 30 day periods between your day, not months...

Comment: Hmm, we would like the number in months, not days. Can we convert it to months?

I guess I could just change day to Month?

Comment: @Kenny If you show some sample data and desired results, we wouldn't have to guess. But it doesn't seem like you're even sure what results you really want. Your question was about the error you were getting, and the answer is you use `DATEDIFF` instead of implicit subtraction (which only works in certain contexts and only with some of the date/time types anyway). If you have a business logic question about whether you should return days or months or how you should calculate that interval, that's something you're going to need to decide - we can't do that for you.

Comment: well you should decide what difference do you want before you will code it. For example, datediff in months between January 31 and February 01 will be 1, because it's different months

Comment: @AaronBertrand and Roman, thank you guys very much for your insightful advise.

I know exactly what I want. I did this using .net.

But users want some data dump and I am trying to convert that code to sql server syntax.

We want it to display months, not days.

I have uploaded at the top a sample of how it looks like on our app.

Comment: @Kenny right but we're still not sure exactly what you mean by "months" - that's why I asked for sample data and desired results.